# Python on Crontab does not execute bash script

Tags: python, bash, cron

```
import subprocess as sub
import re
import os
from datetime import datetime as influx_timestap
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
from collections import OrderedDict

insert_json = []
hostname = str(sub.check_output('hostname')).strip()
location = str(sub.check_output(['ps -ef | grep mgr'], shell=True)).split()
current_dir = os.getcwd()
print("script executed")
gg_location_pattern = re.compile(r'mgr\.prm$')
gg_process_pattertn = re.compile(r'^REPLICAT|^EXTRACT')
for index in location:
    if gg_location_pattern.search(index) != None:
        gg_location = index[:-14]

os.chdir(gg_location)
print("checkpoint1")
get_lag = sub.check_output(str(current_dir) + '/ggsci_test.sh', shell=True)
print("checkpoint2")
processes = get_lag.split("\n")

for process in processes:
    if gg_process_pattertn.search(process) != None:
        lag_at_chkpnt = int((process.split()[3]).split(":")[0]) * 3600 + int((process.split()[3]).split(":")[1]) *60 + int((process.split()[3]).split(":")[2])
        time_since_chkpnt = int((process.split()[4]).split(":")[0]) * 3600 + int((process.split()[4]).split(":")[1]) *60 + int((process.split()[4]).split(":")[2]
)
        process_dict = OrderedDict({"measurement": "GoldenGate_Mon_" + str(hostname) +  "_Graph",
                        "tags": {"hostname": hostname, "process_name": process.split()[2]},
                        "time": influx_timestap.now().isoformat('T'),
                        "fields": {"process_type": process.split()[0], "process_status": process.split()[1],
                        "lag_at_chkpnt": lag_at_chkpnt, "time_since_chkpnt": time_since_chkpnt}})
        insert_json.append(process_dict)


host = 'xxxxxxxx'
port = 'x'
user = 'x'
password = 'x'
dbname = 'x'
print("before client")
client = InfluxDBClient(host, port, user, password, dbname)
client.write_points(insert_json)
print("after client")
```

This code works manually perfect, but on the crontab it is not working. After searching on the internet I found that they say change or set your "PATH" variable on the crontab. I changed my "PATH" variable and it is still not working.

Crontab log file write "checkpoint1" after that there is nothing. So, line not working is `"get_lag = sub.check_output(str(current_dir) + '/ggsci_test.sh', shell=True)"`

What can I do here afterwards?
Take care,

Comment: how do you call this script from within crontab?

Comment: * * * * * /bin/python /gecici/GoldenGate/GoldenGate_Mon/commands_graph.py >> /gecici/GoldenGate/GoldenGate_Mon/x.log

Comment: When I add try-except before that related line I get following result: Command 'ggsci < /home/ggate/ggsci_commands.sh' returned non-zero exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your external script (ggsci_test.sh) has some issues with the paths / general failure.

From the [Python subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) about `subprocess.check_output`:

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The
> CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode
> attribute and any output in the output attribute.

So thats the reason why you see the error when catching it, but not being able to continue.

You should check therefore if your shell script has any issues that need to be solved before.

Comment: Hi again, I found the error, but I do not know how to fix it. When I using subprocess I have to use "shell=True" argument in subprocess.check_output method. Yet our crontab does not allow us to use shell=True. Because of this, I should use subprocess.Popen, but at this time I have to use "ksh" to run my bash script file. Finally, when I run "ggsci < ksh my_bash_script_full_path" due to ggsci command it does not work... I am stuck :(